# how change vuetify component variable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to change the background color of `<v-progress>` by using variable
`$progress-circular-underlay-stroke` but the new value does not affect the output

```
<template>
 <v-progress-circular
        :rotate="360"
        :size="100"
        :width="15"
        value="20"
        color="primary"
      >
        20
      </v-progress-circular>
</template>
<style lang='scss'>
  @import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
  @import '~vuetify/src/components/VProgressCircular/_variables.scss';
  $progress-circular-underlay-stroke = "#FF6859" 
</style>
```

my environment is Vuecli.

Comment: You can't change the SCSS variables from a single file component, you need to change your webpack config. Check out this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/

Comment: I read that link but not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite its style as given below:

```
.v-progress-circular__underlay {
  stroke: #ff6859 !important;
}
```

Comment: thankes to answer. I know this class but I want to use Scss variables in my own component. if I cant use them what use full is Scss variables

Answer (score 0):

If SASS variable change doesn't work for you like `$progress-circular-underlay-stroke = "red"`

Then you can do it via directive and it's more efficient if you're using two different color base progress circles. This will style only one instance and not override your plugin style all over the app

```
---- Todo.vue ----
<v-progress-circular
     :rotate="90"
     :size="186"
     :width="4"
     :value="'25%'"
     :color="red"
     :underlayColor="pink"
     v-drv-progress-circle
    >

--- ProgressCircle.directive.vue
export const drvProgressCircle = {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    const unFillCircle = el.querySelector('.v-progress-circular__underlay')
    const { underlayColor } = vnode.data.attrs
    if (underlayColor) {
        unFillCircle.style.stroke = underlayColor
    }
  }
}
```